# How to use a custom directive in Angular 2 RC6?

Tags: angular

I am having troubles including a custom component (directive) into my angular component.

The component renders and also I can see the directive in the DOM (Chrome Dev Tools). But it's **empty** despite I provided a template.

**home.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './index';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

**typeahead-custom.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'typeahead-custom',
    template: `<div>
    <span>component</span>
<div style="padding-left: 5px">
    </div></div>
    `,
    styleUrls: [
        'app/includes/typeahead-custom/typeahead-custom.css'
    ]
})

export class TypeAheadCustomComponent {

    constructor () { }
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'as-home',
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'app/home/home.css'
    ]
})

export class HomeComponent {
    public myData: any;
    public mySource: any[] = [
        { key:1, name:'Key One' },
        { key:2, name:'Key Two' },
        { key:3, name:'Key Three' },
        { key:4, name:'Key Four' }
    ];

    constructor() { }
}
```

DOM result:

```
.....
<as-home _nghost-btf-4=""><typeahead-custom _ngcontent-btf-4=""></typeahead-custom>
</as-home>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {TypeAheadCustomComponent } from './typeahead-custom.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,TypeAheadCustomComponent   <///----here
    ],
    exports: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
```

Comment: Yes I sorted it out in the end. at the same time :) I'll accept the answer when it let me to!

Comment: Oh That's great ! Have a great time ahead with Angular2.

Comment: what module does this decorator belong to? `HomeModule`?